# Image base64 from remote URL not loading

Tags: angular7

I have a *ngFor loop displaying data and one of the fields is a path to Remote hosted URL.  The data is string with the following format  "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk......"

I have tried

```
<div *ngFor="let list of lists">
   <div>
     <p>{{list.name}}</p>
     <img [src]="list.imagepath"> 
   </div>
</div>
```

There is no error in the browser debug windows just the that the base64 image is not displayed.  The remote URL returns the base64 string without problems and pasting the string directly into `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS...">` works.

Comment: try  `<img [src]="data:image/jpeg;base64, {{list.imagepath}}" />` or `<img data-ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{list.imagepath}}" />`

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p99dnd

Comment: @AlbertK This works fine for me

Comment: But the image can be Jpeg or png and also the list.imagepath contains the URL ie https://www.mycompany.com/v2/base64image/1 where the integer at the end is the index to the base64 image stored in a DB.

Comment: Can you provide Sample JSON?

Comment: [ {"name": "Alice", "imagepath":"https://www.mycompany.com/v2/base64image/1" },  {"name": "Bob", "imagepath":"https://www.mycompany.com/v2/base64image/2" }  ]

Comment: Is this image URL's access over the internet?

Comment: Sorry, no it is not published yet,  still in development.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186343/discussion-between-prashant-pimpale-and-albertk).